# Compile classes with overlapping dependencies

Tags: java, compilation, dependencies

I have two classes. Layout and Board.

Layout has static variables which i'm using in Board class.

Also, i instantiate Board in Layout class.

I cant be able to compile it in command line. javac *.java does work but it throws an exception. How to handle this??

Layout class

```
public class Layout{

  public static int hellovar = 1;

  public static void main(String args[]){
    Board b = new Board();
    b.calculate();
  }
}
```

Board class

```
public class Board {
  public void calculate(){
    int i = Layout.hellovar++;
    System.out.println(i);
  } 
}
```

Comment: code please? so that we see what you are trying to do?

Comment: Please provide the troubled code and the exception trace.  You can hit edit on your question to add more information.

Comment: @SivaSubramaniam edit your question and post the full error.

Comment: Have you tried compiling it in your IDE? Normally the IDE handles these issue for you.

Comment: Ya IDE handles it.. But i want to learn doing it without that.  I want to understand how it must be solved.

Comment: another trick could be to use ANT script with a small task on javac. This will definitely work

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any import statements, kind of hard to tell without the compilation error output.  It would help if you mention your packaging structure.  The following works for me  (FYI using Ubuntu Linux, Java 1.6.0_25):

```
$> javac *.java
$> java Layout
1
```

Can you post your error?

Comment: Both the source files are in the same folder.  I think there is no need for an import statement in this case i guess.  Sorry if i'm wrong.  i'm a newbie trying out different things with java basics.

Answer (score 0):

It is dependency problem.

But the following compiles:

```
javac Board.java Layout.java
```

While this does not compile

```
javac Layout.java Board.java
```

Let me check on the dependency issue and give you an explanation

Comment: Compiling one or the other first doesn't change things for me, both compile and run (using Ubuntu, x86, Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_25-b06).

Comment: @cyber-monk which javac version are you using? i think mine may be old cause of statbility (1.6.0)

Answer (score 0):

one trick is to use an ANT script having a single javac task like -

```
<javac sourcepath="" 
       srcdir="${src}"
       destdir="${build}" >
<include name="**/*.java"/>
</javac>
```